# Netbeans is not including glib.h , Even if it is present as shown by auto-completion. What to do?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans, glib, netbeans-plugins

Glib is installed on my Ubuntu system & I am able to compile using terminal using pkj-config command.

But When i try to include glib.h in Netbeans, Auto completion shows :

[image: Auto Completion ScreenShot]

But when I click glib.h and include it, It says :

[image: Error Shown]

It says, library not found.

I have googled but nothing seems to work.I am very new to Ubuntu system. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to include that header file as `<glib.h>`, not `<glib-2.0/glib.h>` (`/usr/include/glib-2.0` needs to be in your include path).

You need to figure out how to pass the relevant flags to the compiler and linker (from `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` and `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`).  I've never used netbeans, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747691 sounds reasonable.  If that doesn't work just poke around for information on netbeans and pkg-config.